# clojure reduce a seq of maps to a map of vectors

Tags: recursion, clojure, hashmap

I would like to reduce the following seq:

```
({0 "Billie Verpooten"}
 {1 "10:00"}
 {2 "17:00"}
 {11 "11:10"}
 {12 "19:20"})
```

to

```
{:name "Billie Verpooten"
 :work {:1  ["10:00" "17:00"]
        :11 ["11:10" "19:20"]}}
```

but I have no idea to do this.

I was think about a recursive function that uses deconstruction.

Comment: What is the logic behind building the result map?  For example, do you know that the map with key 0 maps to the name, and how do the work numbers "add up"?  If you have an arbitrary function that can take a map and return the appropriate key-value pair, that would work to.

Comment: the map with key `0` indeed always maps to the name and all the rest of map contains pairs that need to be joined (where only the first key is retained, as a sort of id).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a function for reducing a sequence to something in the standard library, and it's called `reduce`. Though in your specific case, it seems appropriate to `remove` the special case key `0` first and `partition` the rest into the pairs of entries that they're meant to be.

The following function gives the result described in your question:

```
(defn build-map [maps]
  (let [entries (map first maps)
        key-zero? (comp zero? key)]
    {:name (val (first (filter key-zero? entries)))
     :work (reduce (fn [acc [[k1 v1] [k2 v2]]]
                     (assoc acc (keyword (str k1)) [v1 v2]))
                   {}
                   (partition 2 (remove key-zero? entries)))}))
```

Comment: aha! it was the partition that I actually missed in my clojure vocabulary (I only started this week) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just for variety here is a different way of expressing an answer by threading sequence manipulation functions:

```
user> (def data '({0 "Billie Verpooten"}
                  {1 "10:00"}
                  {2 "17:00"}
                  {11 "11:10"}
                  {12 "19:20"}))

user> {:name (-> data first first val) 
       :work (as-> data x 
                   (rest x) 
                   (into {} x) 
                   (zipmap (map first (partition 1 2 (keys x))) 
                           (partition 2 (vals x))))}
```

teh `as->` threading macro is new to Clojure 1.5 and makes expressing this sort of function a bit more concise.